# proper way for middleware to terminate responce

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-3.1

I'm using middleware and would like to cancel or redirect a response without filling the log with error messages, at the moment I fail to find a correct way to do this, I have the following code and I'm not happy with it.

```
internal class MyMiddleware
{

    RequestDelegate _next;
    public MyMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        _next = next;
    }

    public Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (context.RequestAborted.IsCancellationRequested)
            return _next(context);

        Uri newUrl;

        //some logic
        if (newUrl != null)
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status307TemporaryRedirect;
            context.Response.Redirect(newUrl.AbsolutePath);
        }
        else
        {
            context.Response.Headers.Clear();
            context.Response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest;
            context.Response.Clear();
            context.Abort();
        }

        return _next(context);
    }
}
```

The middleware get's called no issue however redirect or cancel both fail to give the proper response headers and content. how to properly implement this?

Answer (score 0):

ok, so I figured it out, how to cancel it, just return a completed task and ignore the _next task

```
    context.Response.StatusCode = 403;
    return Task.CompletedTask;
```